# VLOOKUP Excel, results into one cell delimited with commas

Tags: excel, vlookup

[image: Example Data]
How do I get the desired result in column E? I need to look up the dates with VLOOKUP, but ignore the times of them. Then group the results in one cell. Can this be done without a VBA?

Comment: ....................yes................

Answer (score 4):

If you have Excel 2016+ and an O365 subscription you can use `TEXTJOIN` to achieve this

In cell `E2` enter

```
=TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE,IF(DATE(YEAR($A$2:$A$6),MONTH($A$2:$A$6), DAY($A$2:$A$6))=D2,$B$2:$B$6,""))
```

And enter using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image: Results]

Comment: You can shorten it to: `=TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE,IF(INT($A$2:$A$6)=D2,$B$2:$B$6,""))`

Comment: @ScottCraner - Hadn't thought of that. Neat way of removing the timestamp